# How to implement deserializer for a known T type?

Tags: generics, rust, traits, serde

I have a :

```rust
struct Duo<T> 
{
    classroom:String,
    children: T
}
```

where I know that `T` is either a `String` or a `Vec<String>`.

Can I somehow write in code that `T` is either `String` or `Vec<String>`?

I want to implement a deserializer using serde for the T type, having a JSON file where I have either string or Vec.

How do I write a trait for a T type? I don't want to write the trait for the entire Struct. Is it possible? I hope I was clear enough. Thank you!

Comment: Does this duality exist in the data model, or only in the serialization format? That is, is there a difference, semantically, between `"a_string"` and `["a_string"]` that needs to be maintained into the Rust code? Or do you really just want a `Vec<String>` internally, that can be deserialized from either one?

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need to implement it yourself. Just telling the compiler what `T` should be.

You can do 2 things:

Just derive from `Deserialize`

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Duo<T> 
{
    classroom: String,
    children: T
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6b86583368f109fd4e842c24fbe67a48)

Use custom wrapper enum type with the [`untagged`](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#untagged) flag:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum Children {
    Single(String),
    Multi(Vec<String>)
}


#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Duo 
{
    classroom: String,
    children: Children,
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9382aa842f65c96d3486c26caa56afd9)

Comment: This doesn't really help. The JSON file contains multiple objects where the children can be either String or Vec<String>. Your method works if the JSON file only has one of the two types, doesn't it?

Comment: @thebalkandude No, in the first one you need to mark the type when deserializing. In the second one you are already telling that it can be any of those and then you have to check the enum in runtime. Check the playgrounds, I think you may want the second option.

Comment: hmm ok I think that would work but, say that children field actually represent a number or Vector of numbers represented by String, Vec<String>. Say we want to make the sum of all the children. How do we proceed? I don't know if the Children is either a single String or a Vector.

Comment: @thebalkandude, you can add a method to the `Children` enum for that. It doesn't have to deal with the deserialization itself. If they are numbers just change the inner enum constructors with the appropriated types.